Avoiding infinite loops in custom hooks without using useEffectEvent?
Here's an extract from a simple forms library I'm working on. A form has both an initial value and a current value. The current value can be reset to the initial value. Optional, upon reset the initial value can also be changed:
const useForm = ((initialInitialValue: T) => {
  // Uses state since the initial value can be changed by reset:
  const [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState(initialInitialValue);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialInitialValue);

  const reset = useCallback((newInitialValue?: T) => {
    if (newInitialValue !== undefined) {
      setInitialValue(newInitialValue);
    }
    setValue(newInitialValue ?? initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return {reset, setValue, value};
};

Unfortunately, using the reset function easily creates an infinite loop:
// Wait until myInitialValue is available (e.g. from the react-query's useQuery):
useEffect(() => {
  if (myInitialValue === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  reset(myInitialValue);
}, [myInitialValue, reset]);

Since reset changes the hook's initialValue, reset will will be a new function, which will trigger the effect again, in an endless loop.
One could imagine some hacky workarounds, like using a useRef together with the useEffect to only call reset once (if that's appropriate in your application) but that's very brittle as each user of the useForm custom hook must do that (and must be aware that they need to do that). In other words, useForm as written above is a poor, leaky abstraction.
In some future version of React we can use useEffectEvent to achieve a slightly nicer version of the above useRef hack. However,

useEffectEvent is not available today and
it still puts the onus on the caller and still makes it easy to write an infinite loop.

What is the recommended way of writing useForm to not have this property.

Is there a compelling reason why you are calling reset in a useEffect hook instead of in some DOM event handler, e.g. a button click handler, a form submit handler, etc? Maybe you can [edit] to clarify the use case?

@DrewReese the reset happens due to an updated state fetched from the backend by react-query. Think of the case where the user is updating some entity that lives in the backend using a form and that entity changes. In the real code reset also has a keepDirtyFields prop so only unedited fields reset.

Leverage useRef to store the initial value and reset logic. This prevents the dependencies from causing unnecessary re-renders.
const resetRef = useRef();
// Store the reset function in the ref to prevent re-creation
  useEffect(() => {
    resetRef.current = reset;
  }, [reset]);

Change the return statement
 return { reset: resetRef.current, setValue, value };

The resetRef is used to store the reset function to prevent it from being recreated every time initialValue changes. This avoids the infinite loop in your useEffect.
The reset function is still created using useCallback to keep it memoized, but the actual reference used in the component is stable, preventing re-renders caused by the function changing.
An effect is used to update resetRef.current whenever the reset function changes. This ensures that the reference used in the component is always up-to-date, but without triggering additional renders.
In the component we call call reset function from myForm

const MyFormComponent = ({ myInitialValue }) => {
 const { reset, setValue, value } = useForm(myInitialValue);
useEffect(() => {
 useEffect(() => {
 if (myInitialValue === undefined) {
   if (myInitialValue !== undefined) {
   return;
 }
 reset(myInitialValue);
     reset(myInitialValue);
   }
}, [myInitialValue, reset]);
 }, [myInitialValue, reset]);
 return (
   <div>
     <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
     <button onClick={() => reset()}>Reset</button>
   </div>
 );
};

